# Java enum in card class to output in main and build deck in deck class

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm new to this site but have been looking at a lot of info on `enum`s and I am kinda figuring them out but could use some help. What I'm trying to do is get the card constructor in my card class to take in int values and return the rank and suit associated with those values. This is what I'm working with in my Card class.

```java
package blackjack;

public class Card {
    static Rank rank;
    static Suit suit;

    public enum Rank{ACE(1),TWO(2),THREE(3),FOUR(4),FIVE(5),SIX(6),SEVEN(7),
        EIGHT(8),NINE(9),TEN(10),JACK(11),QUEEN(12),KING(13);

        private int code;

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        private Rank(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public static Rank valueOf(int code) {
            for (Rank rank: Rank.values()) { 
                if (rank.getCode()==code) 
                    return rank;
             }
            throw new RuntimeException("INVALID CODE");
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            String s = super.toString();
            return s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }
    }


    public enum Suit{SPADES(1),HEARTS(2),CLUBS(3),DIAMONDS(4);

        private int code;



        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }


        private Suit(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        } 

        public static Suit valueOf(int code) {
            for (Suit suit: Suit.values()) { 
                if (suit.getCode()==code) 
                    return suit;
             }
            throw new RuntimeException("INVALID CODE");
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            String s = super.toString();
            return s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    public Card(int rank,int suit) {
        this.suit = Suit.valueOf(suit);
        this.rank = Rank.valueOf(rank);
    }

    public static void setRank(Rank rank) {
        Card.rank = rank;
    }

    public static Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public static void setSuit(Suit suit) {
        Card.suit = suit;
    }

    public static Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

Here in my main class which is called BlackJack all I really wanna do is create a new card and assign it the rank and suit using ints from the constructor I created in Card and then output it just to make sure its working. I keep getting this crazy error that I cant figure out. Any help would be apprecated! This is my BlackJack/main class.

```java
package blackjack;

public class BlackJack {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Card c1 = new Card(1,1);
        System.out.println(c1.rank.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is a great example of it in *Effective Java* by J.Bloch

Comment: Can you post the afore-mentioned '*crazy error*'?

Comment: You should not use static fields in your Card class to hold the rank and suit. Simply remove the static part of the field declaration. But you should make your enum declaration static `public static enum Rank...` or even expose them as top level enums.

Comment: Why would you use ints at all? You can also iterate over enums.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following edits:

1. Make the enums static
2. If you use `valueOfAlternate` you could get rid of the code, this works only if your cards have a consecutive numbering and your declaration is in that order, since values is 0-based we need to deduct one from the parameter
3. Offer a Constructor that accepts the parameters directly
4. Make the fields of Cards non-static as well as their setters and getters.

```
package blackjack;  

public class Card {
    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;

    public enum Rank {
        ACE(1),TWO(2),THREE(3),FOUR(4),FIVE(5),SIX(6),SEVEN(7),
        EIGHT(8),NINE(9),TEN(10),JACK(11),QUEEN(12),KING(13);

        private final int code;

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        private Rank(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public static Rank valueOf(int code) {
            for (Rank rank: Rank.values()) { 
                if (rank.getCode()==code) 
                    return rank;
             }
            throw new RuntimeException("INVALID CODE");
        }

        public static Rank valueOfAlternate(int code) {
            return Rank.values()[code-1];
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            String s = super.toString();
            return s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }
    }


    public enum Suit{
        SPADES(1),HEARTS(2),CLUBS(3),DIAMONDS(4);

        private final int code;

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        private Suit(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        } 

        public static Suit valueOf(int code) {
            for (Suit suit: Suit.values()) { 
                if (suit.getCode()==code) 
                    return suit;
             }
            throw new RuntimeException("INVALID CODE");
        }

        public static Suit valueOfAlternate(int code) {
            return Suit.values()[code-1];
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            String s = super.toString();
            return s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    public Card(int rank,int suit) {
        this.suit = Suit.valueOf(suit);
        this.rank = Rank.valueOf(rank);
    }

    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

}
```

Without your crazy error description this is the best I can offer.

Comment: THIS IS MY ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - constructor Card in class blackjack.Card cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 at blackjack.BlackJack.main(BlackJack.java:8)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Java inner class  enums are implicitly static.  There's no need for the declaration. Also, he OP should remove the setters from `Card`.  There's no need to ever change a card's values after one gets a card.

Comment: @EricJablow I didn't new about the implicit static inner enums. I've made some edits to reflect your comment.

Comment: It would make little sense for each instance of class `Outer` to have its members of enum `InnerEnum` to differ from any other `Outer`'s inner enums.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your enumerations a constructor with more than one argument. You can also override methods (like `toString`) and create your own methods within an enumeration (like `getValue`).

So your card class might look something like this:

```
public class Card {

    public Enum Suit {

        SPADE(0, "Spade"), HEART(1, "HEART"), ... ;

        private int code = -1;
        private int name = null;

        private Suit(int code, String name) {
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getValue() { return code; }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return name; }

    }

    private Suit suit = null;
    private Rank rank = null;

    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() { return suit; }
    public Rank getRank() { return rank; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return suit.toString() + "-" + rank.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your declaration of `SPADE(0, "Spade"), HEART(1, "HEART"), ... ;` should be inside your enum declaration. But I don't see how this answers OPs question.

Comment: It means he doesn't have to use static methods to get the "value" of an enumeration - which is probably the root cause of his error. EDIT: I should maybe make it more explicit that being able to override `toString` implies you can actually add methods to your enumeration.

Comment: His request was to have a constructor with two ints, in his solution he could already add a constructor that accepts the enums, if he made them static. And you are missing the Rank enum in your solution. And repeating the name of the enum instance does not really help.

Comment: I posted this answer because, in my opinion, taking two integers into a constructor defies the point of having an enumeration. If he's creating a `Card` then he should be working on the abstraction of `Ranks` and `Suits`, not primitive types. (I also didn't give him a complete example but enough to go on.) Repeating the name of the enumeration allows him to change the displayed name of it, if he so chooses. I feel this is a perfectly fine answer because it demonstrates a preferable solution to passing in integer values - if someone asks the wrong question, we should still give the right answer

Comment: @ Leonard. Anyway you could be a little more specific I am only in java1 and dont really know what my solution means.

Comment: OK so after looking at this I kinda figured out what my question should have been. I want to use a loop in a deck class and create an array of card by using an iterate/i but it wont let me call on the number of the enum suit and rank it will only let me call the actual variable ACE or SPADES etc. I want to use the i in a loop to call each rank and suit variable to create the cards and add them to an array index variable to create the deck.

Comment: You don't need to do that at all.  Every enum has a `values` method that returns an array of its members.  So, you can do `for (Suit suit: Suit.values())`. You don't need the int members at all.  Note also that every `Enum E` implements `Comparable<E>`, so you can just use `compareTo()`.

Comment: Eric (and flup, if you look at the above comments) has the right answer to this question, then. Simply `for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) { for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) { cards.add(new Card(suit, rank); }}`